# Closing window is not quitting the application

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I was reading about builder.connect_signals which maps handlers of glade files with methods in your python file. Apparently works, except for the Main Window, which is not destroying when you close it.  If you run it from terminal is still running and have to Ctrl-C to completely close the application.

Here is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
import gtk
#from gi.repository import Gtk
import gtk.glade


class Mixer:

   def __init__(self):
       self.gladefile = "mixer3.glade"
       self.wTree = gtk.Builder()
       self.wTree.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
       window = self.wTree.get_object("window1")
       #if (window):
        #  window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

       #line_btn = self.wTree.get_object("toggle_linein")
       #line_btn.connect("on_toggle_linein_activate", btn_linein_activated)
       self.wTree.connect_signals(self)
       window.show_all() # must have!


   def on_toggle_linein_clicked(self, widget):
       print "Clicked"


   def Destroy(self, obj):
      gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   m = Mixer()
   gtk.main()
```

Comment: In 2015 you should really be using GTK+3 through the introspected bindings (I see it commented up there), PyGTK is unmantained for many years now. Anyhow that's not the problem, PyGTK has always been working properly and I'm fairly sure the problem it's in your code or most likely in your glade file. Are you sure in glade you are connecting the "Destroy" signal properly?

Comment: Uh, that makes me think I didn't select an appropriate UI library and designer. I used pyGTK with GTK2 because I had problems with the files generated by Glade3, so I used an earlier version of glade which give me less problems.

Comment: So, I already done some work using this, is there any better way to design easily a GUI application considering that is for Raspbian (Debian for Raspberry Pi) and don't want to install a very large library to support it?

Answer (score 1):

On closing window your window destroying but main loop of program don't stop, you must connect **destroy** event to the method/function that quit from this loop that ran from last line of code.
Make some change in below lines of codes:

```
#if (window):
    #  window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
```

change to:

```
if (window):
    window.connect("destroy", self.Destroy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GtkApplication` and `GtkApplicationWindow` to manage it for you. When Application has no more open windows, it will automatically terminate.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gio

class Mixer(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mixer, self).__init__(application_id="org.test",
                                    flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE)

    def do_activate(self):
        self.gladefile = "mixer3.glade"
        self.wTree = Gtk.Builder()
        self.wTree.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        # window1 must be an ApplicationWindow in glade file
        window = self.wTree.get_object("window1")
        self.add_window(window) # window should be added to application
                                # but only after 'activate' signal
        window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   m = Mixer()
   m.run() # No gtk.main(), GtkApplication manages it
```