# Closing the GUI window does not end the program

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, python-2.x, glade

I have been reading a lot about Glade and been playing with it for the last couple of days to get a basic Python GUI application working. I was able to get a window showing, but whenever I close it I get a ghost process in the terminal from which my program is launched - the application just hangs, but the window is hidden. The process can only be killed via kill - it does not respond to Ctrl-C or Ctrl-D.

## The Adventures - what have I tried

I have a function in my code called `onDeleteWindow`
All modifications to the code have been happening inside this function.

I have consulted a variety of sources including [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147183/closing-window-is-not-quitting-the-application) and [this GTK3 documentation example](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html) and here are the different methods that I have extracted from those sources and, of course, tried:

**Method 1:** `window.connect("destroy", self.Destroy)`
**Method 2**: `self.quit` or `self.quit()`
**Method 3:** `gtk.main_quit()`
All of them lead to the same outcome - ghost process. The example from the GTK3 documentation also leads to the same outcome, if it is copy and pasted as is.

## My application and code

### somegui.py:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

class Handler:
    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        self.quit()


    def onButtonPressed(self, button):
        print("Hello World!")

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("somegui.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

window = builder.get_object("MainWindow")
window.show_all()

builder.get_objects()

Gtk.main()
```

### somegui.glade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface domain="">
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="MainWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Hi there</property>
    <property name="startup_id">MainWindow</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Hi there!</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Awesome button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="relief">none</property>
            <property name="yalign">0.56000000238418579</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

**Gtk version**: (according to XML) 3.10
**Python version:** (checked by launching the interpreter) 2.7.6

What am I doing wrong? I have been trying to get it working for the last couple of days with no progress. Any hints would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** It appears there were issues with the .glade file, I have copied and pasted its source again, hopefully this will work.

**EDIT2:** Thank you everyone who have taken their time to answer. The issue was that the handlers were not paired with the GUI itself.

Comment: The first thing you tried but with `Gtk.main_quit()` instead of `self.quit()` should do it. What is `self.quit()`?

Comment: I don't think `onDeleteWindow` is actually called in this code. It's enough to do `window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)`.

Comment: Or simple sys.exit()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Are you editing the XML by hand? Your Glade file is corrupt, because you added 2 children to a Window. That is not allowed. You need to add a container (e.g. a GtkBox) to the window and then put all other widgets inside that box.

In your Pyhthon code you also call `self.quit()` But self is in this case just a Python object. And it doesn't inherit any methods from GTK. Look another time at how the classes are defined in the Python-GTK3-Tutorial (https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

As Leonardo mentioned you need to also define your signals in Glade and then use the same name in Python so that your handlers are connected. Here is where you need to set your window-destroy signal:

[image]

Here is the basic setup that I would use:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

class Handler(object):
    def __init__(self, builder):
        self.builder = builder
        self.window = builder.get_object("window1")
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_window1_destroy(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_button1_clicked(self, button):
        print("Hello World!")

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("somegui.glade")
hdlr = Handler(builder)
builder.connect_signals(hdlr)
Gtk.main()
```

And the UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Hi there</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window1_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Hi There!</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Awesome Button!</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Indeed, the file got corrupted, probably because I copied and pasted it wrong (unintentionally). Thank you for such a detailed example! Not connecting the handlers properly was indeed the issue, as was also pointed out by Leonardo.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to open this `somegui.glade` file with Glade. The application reports a premature closing of tags.

Anyway, you are not connecting the signal to the handler. The `connect_signals` method would work if you used Glade to map which methods will handle which signals from which widgets. To map signals to methods, open your `.ui` or `.glade` file with Glade, select a widget (say, a button), and then click the "Signals" tab in the lower part of the right pane. Usually you should need only to write the method name in the "handler" column, in the row corresponding to the signal you want to be handled.

Comment: By the way, are you sure you don't want to use a `.ui` file, instead of a `.glade` file?

Comment: Probably I corrupted it with endless copying and pasting. The only file that got produced by glade was a .glade flie. I read that some versions do also produce a .ui file, but that wasn't the case with this version. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Glade 3 supports GtkBuilder since it was first written, and Glade 2 supported GtkBuilder too. You can choose the file type when you are saving it, or you can type the extension directly.